# SQL query for multiple conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table of users who have subscribed to different plans of a streaming services and other data about the said users.
Something similar to this,

| Name | Plan | Status | Subscription Date | Cancel Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Ajax | 5-user | Active | Jan 2021 | - |
| Zack | 1-User | Active | Mar 2021 | - |
| Ray | 5-User | Inactive | Apr 2020 | Dec 2020 |
| Ray | 1-User | Active | Dec 2020 | - |
| Jack | 1-user | Inactive | Nov 2020 | Jun 2021 |
| Kal | 5-user | Inactive | Jan 2022 | Feb 2022 |
| Bruce | 5-User | Active | Jan 2020 | - |
| Kal | 1-User | Active | Feb 2022 | - |
| Diana | 1-User | Inactive | Jul 2015 | Jul 2020 |

I need to write a sql query to find out the list of users who have cancelled the 5 user plan and bought the 1-user plan. Names - WHERE Plan=5-user and status= Inactive + Plan = 1-user and Status=Active.
Also, the result should displav the names with the current active plan.(would help if all the other columns in the table are displayed along with it too)

I tried

```
SELECT NAME
FROM Table
WHERE Plan = 5-user AND Status = Inactive
OR Plan = 1-User AND Status = Active
```

EXPECTED RESULT :
|Ray|1-User|Dec 2020
|Kal|1-User|Feb 2022

P.S I'm new to this site and I have just started learning SQL, I apologise in advance for any error in my question framing.

Comment: Tag the RDBMS you use.

Comment: Is that sample data or the expected result? We need both anyway, a [mcve].

Comment: I'm new to this, sorry. Will follow the instructions properly next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the `EXISTS` operator as the following:

```
SELECT Name, Plan, Status, 
       DATE_FORMAT(SubscriptionDate,'%M %Y') SubscriptionDate
FROM table_name T
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table_name D 
              WHERE D.Name=T.Name AND
                    D.Plan='5-User' AND D.Status='Inactive' AND
                    D.SubscriptionDate<T.SubscriptionDate
             )
AND Plan='1-User' AND Status ='Active'
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/zmWKtZBq).

Answer (score 0):

We can use `INTERSECT` to perform an intersection between the two types of people, namely ones who have purchased `[Import, Apple]` and `[Native, Orange]`.

```sql
SELECT 
    "name"
FROM
    people
WHERE
    people.fruit = "Apple"
    AND
    people.type = "Import"
INTERSECT
SELECT 
    "name"
FROM
    people
WHERE
    people.fruit = "Orange"
    AND
    people.type = "Native"
```

Comment: Hi Intersect did not work.
I'm sorry if I left out any data.

Answer (score 0):

In this case I suggest you to use `UNION` operator

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE Plan = 5-user AND Status = Inactive

UNION

SELECT *
FROM Table
OR Plan = 1-User AND Status = Active
```

Comment: Hi,thank you for answering, but wouldn't this give me users who have either got the 5 user plan or the 1 user plan.
I want 'only' the names of people who have cancelled the 5 user and also bought the 1 - user.